# What is the reason for having an android dialog created in a fragment instead of being created directly by an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm in the process of learning to develop apps in Android, and I am a bit confused by the docs. I have an activity with a button which is initially filled with a date I got from the **Calendar** class. When the user clicks on this button, a **DatePicker** dialog would show up and allow me to set a new date, which should then be written back to that button's text and be used for further processing.

I see the [Android Pickers documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) suggests you to create a **DatePickerFragment** extending **DialogFragment**, like reproduced here:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

I understood the date set on the dialog will be made available from the **onDateSet** method, which is the implementation of the **DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener** interface, but what I fail to see is why not just call **DatePickerDialog** directly from the main activity? (in my case it is just what I ended up doing and it works fine...).

From my novice point of view it seems that implementing a **DatePickerFragment** is acting like an apparently unnecessary mid layer between **Activity** and the **DatePickerDialog**, making it harder than it should be in the sense that for communicating the date set on **DatePickerFragment.onDateSet** to the main activity would require the interface to be also implemented by the main activity and to communicate the initial date to the fragment I would have to do it through a **Bundle** object, like shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Is this just a matter of documentation trying to be generalist and start off from a fragment instead of activity (I get the feeling a fragment is a bit like a lightweight activity) or there is really some advantage or thing I'm missing so I don't call the dialog directly from the activity?

Comment: DialogFragment helps you handle orientation changes, which are a pain with a regular dialog. With a regular dialog, you need to dismiss it in onStop, then in onStart you need to check whether you need to show it (are we in an orientation change or just regular onStart with no dialog showing?) DialogFragment solves all of this.

Comment: What V M said, on top of the idea that using fragments gives you flexibility across devices.

Comment: Hmm. That seems like a good reason indeed. They should point out things like that in the docs.. it would avoid some lost newbies suffering.. heh

Comment: As a matter of fact they do point out: (on the Dialog docs): These classes define the style and structure for your dialog, but you should use a DialogFragment as a container for your dialog. The DialogFragment class provides all the controls you need to create your dialog and manage its appearance, instead of calling methods on the Dialog object.". Too much to read... sometimes things go by unnoticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're new to Android and haven't yet run into it, let me break it to you: handling orientation changes in Android is a pain. To make it short: the Activity gets recreated every time you change orientation. And all your data members like Dialogs become null.

To combat this there are a couple of ways to handle orientation changes and having a "retained fragment" is one of them. So a DialogFragment is a flavour of this "retained fragment" (don't quote me on this), that doesn't get destroyed on orientation change.

More on this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html